# morris.js line update ymin

Tags: javascript, charts, morris.js

Is there any way to update the ymin of a morris.js line/area?
I've tried it with:

```
chart.ymin = 10
```

but the ymin is still 0.

When it`s not possible in morris.js, are there any other chart libarys that include such a feature?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Solution 1**

Make sure you set the Morris parameter `resize` to true.

Then, on your action, you can set the `ymin`, redraw the chart and make sure the chart is well positioned (trigger a window resize):

```
chart.ymin = 10;
chart.redraw();
$(window).trigger("resize");
```

Please try the following snippet:

```js
var data = [
   { Date: '2016-01-01', Sales: 10 },
   { Date: '2016-01-02', Sales: 20 },
   { Date: '2016-01-03', Sales: 40 },
   { Date: '2016-01-04', Sales: 5 },
   { Date: '2016-01-05', Sales: 50 }
];

var chart = new Morris.Line({
  element: 'chartLine',
  data: data,
  xkey: 'Date',
  ykeys: ['Sales'],
  labels: ['Sales'],
  resize: true,
  xLabels: 'day',
  parseTime: false
});

$(".ymin").on("click", function() {
  chart.ymin = 10;
  chart.redraw();
  $(window).trigger("resize");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/raphael/2.1.0/raphael-min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/morris.js/0.5.1/morris.min.js"></script>
<link href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/morris.js/0.5.1/morris.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div id="chartLine"></div>
<div class="ymin">Set ymin</div>
```

---

**Solution 2**

Set the Morris parameter `resize` to false for your temperature chart.

Make sure you include the Morris CSS available on the [Morris GitHub](http://morrisjs.github.io/morris.js/). Without this CSS, hovering the chart will display the data at the bottom of the chart and will hide the x axis on the next data update from the `setInterval`.

Remove the code trying to get/set the chart height, triggering a window resize and calling the temperature chart redraw.

Finally add the following code in your `$(document).ready` function:

```
var delay = (function () {
    var timer = 0;
    return function (callback, ms) {
        clearTimeout(timer);
        timer = setTimeout(callback, ms);
    };
})();

$(window).resize(function () {
    delay(function () {
        TemperatureChart.redraw();
    }, 300);
}).trigger('resize');
```

Please try the following fork of your CodePen: [codepen.io/krlzlx/pen/prwMLr](https://codepen.io/krlzlx/pen/prwMLr)

Comment: Thanks, it works fine. Except one little (after some hours a big) issue. After every time I execute it, all charts, not only the one chart that i change get bigger by a random amount of pixels. ( http://imgur.com/a/cDG90) The page should look like this: http://imgur.com/a/0mKCm . Do you have a idea or is it the best way to open a issue at morris js?

Comment: Unfortunately Morris has not been updated for some time now so I don't think you'll get help on an issue. I struggled too with charts getting bigger. I managed to resolve this issue but don't remember exactly how. You can try to set the `svg` height like `$('svg').height(800)` if I'm correct. Tell me if it helps.

Comment: Hey, what I try to do is sth like this: `var heightBefore = document.getElementById("chart").firstChild.height.animVal.value;
chart.ymin = response.data.chart.minimum.temperature;
chart.redraw();
$(window).trigger("resize");
document.getElementById("chart").firstChild.height = heightBefore;`. The height i get is fine, but i cannot change the height of the chart? how do you change your height?

Comment: Sorry I don't have my source code right now. I can check it on monday at work.

Comment: I looked at my source code but it's unclear now how I resolved the chart getting bigger than expected. I do have this line in my javascript: `$('svg').height(450)`. Maybe if you can create a [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/) or if you have an online page that reproduce your issue, I can try to fix it.

Comment: Finally found a fix! I've updated my answer and provided a fork of your CodePen: [codepen.io/krlzlx/pen/prwMLr](https://codepen.io/krlzlx/pen/prwMLr)

Comment: hi, thank you. Currently i don't have as much time as I want. I will check it out in the next few days. And a big thanks again